# SP 10 Designer Workflow not working on Item created

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have 2 list, source list and dependent list, dependent list have lookup column up of source list. while after any item created, a workflow needs to create/update/copy items to a field in dependent list from source list based on lookup column. 
I made workflow, everything is fine but it is not working after item is created, workflow status will be canceled. but it will work while same item is edited, the workflow properties (status) changed as programmed, and items get copied to proper list.

Is it workflow problem or flaw in my design. encountering this problem for first time.

Source list is List and dependent list is Document library.